# string in place of int in c

Tags: c, string, int, infinite-loop

//why the code starts printing retry infinitely if i wrongly
enter a string in place of int i in terminal

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{  
    int i,j=0;
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%d",&i);
        if(i==10)
        {
            printf("you got the max! YOU WON\n");
            break;
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("%s\n","retry" );
                }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it is due to mismatch of data type

Comment: because you have an infinite loop until you enter 10.

Comment: `scanf` does not consume input it can't convert. `scanf` is stupid most of the time, use `fgets` (NEVER `gets`!) in combination with `sscanf` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try consuming (flushing) on bad input:

```
else {
  while ((j = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && j != EOF);
  printf("%s\n", "retry");
}
```

An alternative using `fgets` (is preferable because it consumes the whole line) and `strtol`:

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* fgets, printf */
#include <stdlib.h> /* strtol */
#include <string.h> /* strchr */

int main(void) /* No args */
{  
    char buf[128], *p;
    int i;

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)) {
        if ((p = strchr(buf, '\n')) != NULL) { 
            *p = '\0'; /* remove newline */
        }
        i = (int)strtol(buf, &p, 10); /* Base 10 */
        if (*p != '\0' || i != 10)  {
            printf("retry\n");
        } else {
            printf("you got the max! YOU WON\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Read fails because of you inputted wrong type and `i` will have garbage value.

Add initialization to `i`:

```
int i=0, j=0;
```

`scanf` returns number of succesful reads. Add return value check to `scanf`:

```
    int r = scanf("%d",&i); // Will return 1 if 1 argument was successully read
    if(r == 1 && i == 10)
    {
        //do something
    }
```

**Edit:**

As others have pointed out, it seems that `scanf` doesn't consume incoming bytes if input is wrong. Thus you might want to replace it wit `fgets` and `sscanf`:

```
    int r;
    char temp[32];
    fgets(temp, 32, stdin);      // Read input to temporary buffer
    r = sscanf(temp, "%d", &i);  // Try to convert value on buffer
    if(r == 1 && i == 10)
    {
        //do something
    }
```

Comment: i like your idea and tried it for my purpose and put a switch in while loop but it still goes infinite
{
int j=1,i=0,svalue;
while(j)
{
svalue=scanf("%d",&i);
switch(svalue)
{
case 1: print...won;
j=0;
break;
default : print retry ;
break;
}
so why here it print retry infinitely if a string is entered???